# Add maximum XLM on Standalone Network

Tags: stellar-core, accounts

Currently, Stellar Network has maximum 100 Billion lumens. I want to ask if it is possible to add more lumens to existing **Standalone** (private) Stellar Network?

Answer (score 1):

Recently lumens were removed from circulation. There will now only be 50 billion in existence. Read [SDF's Next Steps](https://www.stellar.org/blog/sdfs-next-steps/) for more info:

> All told, there are now exactly 50 billion lumens in existence.

Adding lumens would be difficult. It would require a core protocol change. So while it may be "*possible*" it would be very unlikely, as you would need the Stellar validators to vote in favor of that change.

Comment: I don't use public Stellar Network, but standalone private Stellar Network for private use.. We can actually change maximum xlm in the circulation. But i'm wondering whether we add new xlm to the circulation dynamically in private network..